# Замена ссылок по регулярному выражению.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Нужно заменить все встречающиеся в строке подстроки типа www.site.ru и подобные на ссылки, за исключением тех, которые уже являются ссылками.
Т.е.

```
$string="...text www.google.ru ... <a href='http://yandex.ru'>Яндекс</a> ... http://gogo.ru..."
```

Заменяется на:

```
$string="...text <a href='http://www.google.ru'>www.google.ru</a> ... <a href='http://yandex.ru'>Яндекс</a> ... <a href='http://gogo.ru'>http://gogo.ru</a>..."
```

Сделал такую регулярку:

```
 $string=preg_replace("/((https?:\/\/)|(www)|(https?:\/\/www))([^((https?:\/\/)|(www)|(https?:\/\/www))(<a)(<\/a>)]+)/", "<a href='$1$5'>$5</a>", $sring);
```

Чего-то она не хочет работать...

Answer (score 1):

есть, например достаточно простого:

```
(?<!href=')(?:((https?://)|(www\.))[^\.]+\S{2,3})
```

либо с ограничением жадности отрицания, если будут косяки, хотя должно быть одинаково (проверяйте сами)

```
(?<!href=')(?:((https?://)|(www\.))[^\.]+?\.\S{2,3})
```

Результат для текста:

```
"...text www.google.ru ... <a href='http://yandex.ru'>Яндекс</a> ...
http://gogo.ru..."
```

match будет: www.google.ru и http://gogo.ru, но не http://yandex.ru

Примечание:

- если для **href='** допустимы различные варианты существования, то следует также добавить обработку этого условия

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу таким образом:

```
$string=preg_replace("/<a href=('|\")(.+)('|\")()>(.+)<\/a>/is",'$2', $string);

$string=preg_replace("/((https?:\/\/)|(www.)|(https?:\/\/www.))([^\s\t\r\n(https?)(www)]+)/is","<a href='http://$5'>$5</a>", $string);
```

Т.е. сначала "разворачиваем" все существующие ссылки. А потом "упаковываем" все, что похоже не url.

Правда, думаю, есть и более изящные решения.